# mandar para outra página depois do AJAX

Tags: jquery, html

Depois do `AJAX` ser feito queria que se desse a mensagem de "sucesso" abri-se uma nova aba.

AJAX:

```
$.post('registo-entrada.php',{ 
                id_ficha:id_ficha, 
                equip_ficha:equip_ficha, 
                pw_ficha:pw_ficha, 
                so_ficha:so_ficha, 
                categ_ficha:categ_ficha, 
                avaria_ficha:avaria_ficha, 
                orc_ficha: orc_ficha,
                peri_ficha:peri_ficha, 
                data_ficha:data_ficha, 
                mala_ficha:mala_ficha, 
                bateria_ficha:bateria_ficha, 
                carregador_ficha:carregador_ficha, 
                obs_ficha:obs_ficha, 
                backup_ficha:backup_ficha,
                contribuinte:contr
            },
            function(data)
            {
                if(data == "fail")
                {
                    sweetAlert('Erro', 'Entrada recusada!', 'error');

                }else
                {
                    window.open("ficha-tecnica.php?id_ficha="+id_ficha,'_blank');
                    swal('Sucesso!', 'Entrada realizada com sucesso!', 'success');

                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

basta inverter a ordem dos comandos!

```
swal('Sucesso!', 'Entrada realizada com sucesso!', 'success');
window.open("ficha-tecnica.php?id_ficha="+id_ficha,'_blank');
```

Comment: já tinha tentado, mas não resultou.